# Can't get TeeChart into VS2010

Tags: teechart

I am trying to add TeeChart to a VS2010 C++ project. I don't want to drag the TeeChart icons onto a dialog as I want to create the chart in my code to display at runtime. I have installed the TeeChart demo version on my PC, but I can't see an entry in the registry - is that ok?
I was expecting to just have to import a dll into my project and then call the methods, but I can't see from the help files what dll to use, or do I have to include a .lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The demo version is fully functional but doesn't install any design-time license and expires after 40 days. You should use TeeChart.dll for your projects.